# EM waves - orthogonality - amplitude/phase angle

Tags: trigonometry, orthogonality

> A plane electromagnetic wave has the shape:
>
> $\vec{E}(\vec{r},t)=E_0\cdot cos(\vec{k}\vec{r}-\omega t)\cdot \vec{e}_y$
>
> $\vec{B}(\vec{r},t)=(B_1\cdot cos(\vec{k}\vec{r}-\omega t)+B_2\cdot sin(\vec{k}\vec{r}-\omega t))\cdot \vec{e}_z=B_0\cdot cos(\vec{k}\vec{r}-\omega t+\phi)\cdot \vec{e}_z$
>
> In what direction is $\vec{k}$ facing?
>
> Determine the amplitude $B_0$ and the phase change $\phi$ between $\vec{E}$ and $\vec{B}$.

We got this one in our lecture of experimental physics and it kind of bugs me because I can't find the right approach to this one.

How can I get from what is given to the direction of $\vec{k}$. I mean, I know that electromagnetic wave is moving along the x-axis from that, meaning $\vec{r}$ is too? Can I conclude the direction from the fact that there is a dot product between $\vec{k}$ and $\vec{r}$?

About the second part: In general $E$ and $B$ are in phase, right? Since that's not the case here, can I assume that it results from a reflection on a surface? But how would I get to $B_0$ and the phase change without explicit values for $\omega$ and such?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Electromagnetic waves have the property that the electric and magnetic field components are orthogonal (perpendicular) to the direction of propagation. In your example the electric field points in the $y$-direction, and the magnetic field points in the $z$-direction. From this we can conclude that the wave propagates in the (positive or negative) $x$-direction. Hence the vectorial wave-factor $k$ is of the form: $(k_x, 0, 0)$. Through the dot product between $k$ and $r$ the spatial dependence of the wave is of the form $k_x x$.

For the second part, you just need to show that you can convert the first expression for the magnetic field (with a cosine and a sine) into the second expression (a cosine with a phase shift), or vice versa. This is standard mathematics. You only need to know the rule for expressing $cos(a+b)$ as a sum, and apply it to the RHS.

Comment: You're talking about $cos(\alpha+\beta)=cos(\alpha)cos(\beta)-sin(\alpha)sin(\beta)$, right? I did that, but I still couldn't find an expression for $B_0$ and neither could I find the phase angle $\phi$.

Comment: Yes. If you use the cosine rule, you get $B_1 = B_0 cos(\phi)$ and $B_2 = -B_0 sin(\phi)$. Therefore $B_0 = \sqrt(B_1 ^2 + B_2 ^2)$ and $\phi = -arctan(B_2/B_1)$.

Comment: It seems you also have a problem with saying "Thank you".

Comment: I'm sorry. Yesterday I was ill and slept through all day. Thank you for the help. Always been struggling with trigonometric identities such as these.

Comment: Okay ! I am glad I could help you with these questions.